# missing esent.h

Tags: c++, esent

I am trying to run this program but i keep getting the error "esent.h No such file or directory"

```
#undef JET_VERSION
#define JET_VERSION 0x0501

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <esent.h>

// One possible error-handling strategy is to jump to an error-handling
// label whenever an ESENT call fails.
#define Call(func) { \
       err = (func); \
       if(err < JET_errSuccess) { \
       goto HandleError; \
       } \
} \

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
       JET_ERR err;
       JET_INSTANCE instance;
       JET_SESID sesid;
       JET_DBID dbid;
       JET_TABLEID tableid;

       JET_COLUMNDEF columndef = {0};
       JET_COLUMNID columnid;
```

What could be the problem?.

Comment: Do `#include`s of other Windows SDK headers work properly?

Comment: where do you put esent library?

Comment: I dont have the windows SDK installed,i uninstalled it yesterday.I will install it and see.

Comment: @Hoang I have my esent.lib at C:\Dev-Cpp\lib and esent.h at C:\Dev-Cpp\include

Comment: I am using Dev C++ and i got a lot of errors.I have the whole code http://sync.in/ieFRKZZ31C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the express version of MS Visual Studio installed and including the esent.h is no problem. Maybe you should try this as it's free (for personal use) anyway.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem.